# Vue: nested for loop, inner v-if condition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this code to display elements in the `colors` array as pairs of two colors:

**TestNested.vue**:

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">

    <div v-for="(first, i) in this.colors" v-bind:key="first">

      <div v-for="(second, j) in this.colors" v-bind:key="second"
        v-if="first === 'GREEN' && second==='BLUE'"
      >

        {{first + "-" + second}}

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "TestNested",

data() {
  return {
    isDone: false,

    colors: []
  }
},

created() {
  this.colors.push("RED");
  this.colors.push("GREEN");
  this.colors.push("BLUE");

  this.isDone = true;
}

}
</script>

<style scoped>

.container  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

div  {
  margin: 0.5em;
}

</style>
```

It displays:

[image]

If I add an `if` condition inside the second `for` loop:

```js
<div v-for="(second, j) in this.colors" v-bind:key="second"
        v-if="first === 'GREEN'"
>
```

It only displays a color pair that starts with `GREEN`:

[image]

However if I add a second condition, to only display pairs that start with `GREEN` and end with `BLUE`:

```js
<div v-for="(second, j) in this.colors" v-bind:key="second"
        v-if="first === 'GREEN' && second === 'BLUE'"
>
```

nothing is displayed.

Why doesn't a `GREEN-BLUE` pair get displayed? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the GREEN-BLUE pair is not displayed when you add the second condition to the v-if directive is that the second for loop is iterating over the colours array in the same order as the first for loop. This means that when the first for loop is iterating over the GREEN element, the second for loop is also iterating over the GREEN element, and the v-if directive is only true when the second for loop is also iterating over the BLUE element.
To fix this issue, you can modify the second for loop to start iterating from the index of the current element in the first for loop. This way, the second for loop will only iterate over the elements that come after the current element in the first for loop.

```html
<div v-for="(first, i) in colors" :key="first">
  <div v-for="(second, j) in colors.slice(i + 1)" :key="second"
       v-if="first === 'GREEN' && second === 'BLUE'">
    {{ first + '-' + second }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it exclude some pairs? Your `v-for` when the `v-if` is removed produces pairs: `RED-GREEN, RED-BLUE, GREEN-BLUE`. However I need all pairs to be potentially present. Also your code (when the `v-if` is present) displays nothing for me

Comment: To display all possible pairs of colours from the array, you can use a computed property to generate the pairs and then iterate over the computed property in the template.
<div class="container">
    <div v-for="pair in colorPairs" :key="pair">
      {{ pair[0] }} - {{ pair[1] }}
    </div>
  </div>

********* computed: {
    colorPairs() {
      const pairs = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.colors.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < this.colors.length; j++) {
          pairs.push([this.colors[i], this.colors[j]]);
        }
      }
      return pairs;
    }
  }